# Responsive images in a grid

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have four images that should be aligned like so:

```
 ____________
|1    |4     |
|_____|      |
|2 |3 |      |
|__|__|______|
```

They need to have no space between them, are 100% of the viewport's width, and, here's the kicker, they need to be responsive.

So my question is, what are best practices to do something seemingly simple like this? Use img tags and size the images exactly (before upload)? Use background images and size them with CSS, then resize them on page resize with JS? Some other way?

I should say that I'm using Boostrap 3 with rows and columns to do this, but wasn't able to make the column heights a percentage height.

Thanks!!

Comment: The outer border — is that the viewport or a box within the window? In other words will the aspect ratio change with different screen sizes or just the total size?

Comment: @MarkM The outer border is the viewport, but the images only have to fill the width. Their aspect ratios will always be static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Bootstrap grid modified with CSS and make sure natural widths and heights of the images add up correctly:

DEMO: https://jsbin.com/caramo

[image]

**HTML**

```
   <div class="container">
    <h2>Flush Grid</h2>
    <div class="row flush-grid">
       <div class="col-sm-6">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/400/fashion" alt=""> 
          <div class="row flush-grid">
             <div class="col-xs-6"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/400/food" alt="" ></div>
             <div class="col-xs-6"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/400/city" alt="" ></div>
          </div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-6 row">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
             <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/800/city" alt="" >
          </div>
       </div>
       <!--/.row.flush-grid -->
    </div>
    <!--/.container-->
```

**CSS**

```
/* Flush Grid */
.row.flush-grid img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    float:left;
}
.row.flush-grid {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}
.row.flush-grid [class*="col-"] { padding:0;}
.row.flush-grid [class*="col-"].row { padding:0;margin:0;}
```

Comment: This looks like the best solution. Size the images exactly and strip away the unneeded Bootstrap styles.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to create a responsive wrapper, set the wrapper to be relatively positioned, and then absolutely position the children of the wrapper.

I just tested this and it worked great. I set my body to 100% height and width, and then the wrapper to 50% of that. On browser resize, the wrapper shrinks, and so do the images, all while maintaining their aspect ratio and positioning in the group.

CSS:

```
.wrapper {

    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 50%;
    width: 50%;

}

.one, .two, .three, .four {

    position: absolute;

}

.one {

    width: 50%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;

}

.two {

    width: 25%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;

}

.three {

    width: 25%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 25%;

}

.four {

    width: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;

}
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="wrapper">

    <img src="../images/one.jpg" class="one"> 

    <img src="../images/two.jpg" class="two"> 

    <img src="../images/three.jpg" class="three"> 

    <img src="../images/four.jpg" class="four"> 

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is an elegant solution, but I like the minimal CSS approach of Christina's.